# BigInteger parsing on Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, int, biginteger

I'm actually working on a IBAN key verification function.

To get the key i do something like :

```
string theKey = (98 - ((int64.Parse(value)) % 97)).ToString();
```

The problem is that my value is something longer than 19. So i need to use BigInteger from System.Numerics.

This references doesn't include the Parse() method.

I need a solution that would allow me to use 23char integer on Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on MSDN gave me a class that comes with Parse/TryParse, it works really good and i hope it'll help. Thanks for the decimal solution though, but it appears that i need to use 30 digits int as well, so biginteger was a must have :

```
public static class BigIntegerHelper
    {
        public static BigInteger Parse(string s)
        {
            return Parse(s, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }

        public static BigInteger Parse(string s, IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            return Parse(s, NumberStyles.Integer, provider);
        }

        public static BigInteger Parse(string s, NumberStyles style)
        {
            return Parse(s, style, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }

        public static BigInteger Parse(string s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            BigInteger result;
            if (TryParse(s, style, provider, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            throw new FormatException();
        }

        public static bool TryParse(string s, out BigInteger b)
        {
            return TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out b);
        }

        public static bool TryParse(string s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider formatProvider, out BigInteger value)
        {
            if (formatProvider == null)
            {
                formatProvider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            }
            if ((style & ~(NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)) != NumberStyles.None)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
            NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo)formatProvider.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo));
            uint num = ((style & NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) != NumberStyles.None) ? 16u : 10u;
            int num2 = 0;
            bool flag = false;
            if ((style & NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite) != NumberStyles.None)
            {
                while (num2 < s.Length && IsWhiteSpace(s[num2]))
                {
                    num2++;
                }
            }
            if ((style & NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign) != NumberStyles.None)
            {
                int length = numberFormatInfo.NegativeSign.Length;
                if (length + num2 < s.Length && string.Compare(s, num2, numberFormatInfo.NegativeSign, 0, length, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.None) == 0)
                {
                    flag = true;
                    num2 += numberFormatInfo.NegativeSign.Length;
                }
            }
            value = BigInteger.Zero;
            BigInteger bigInteger = BigInteger.One;
            if (num2 == s.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= num2; i--)
            {
                if ((style & NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite) != NumberStyles.None && IsWhiteSpace(s[i]))
                {
                    int num3 = i;
                    while (num3 >= num2 && IsWhiteSpace(s[num3]))
                    {
                        num3--;
                    }
                    if (num3 < num2)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    i = num3;
                }
                uint num4;
                if (!ParseSingleDigit(s[i], (ulong)num, out num4))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (num4 != 0u)
                {
                    value += num4 * bigInteger;
                }
                bigInteger *= num;
            }
            if (value.Sign == 1 && flag)
            {
                value = -value;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private static bool IsWhiteSpace(char ch)
        {
            return ch == ' ' || (ch >= '\t' && ch <= '\r');
        }

        private static bool ParseSingleDigit(char c, ulong radix, out uint result)
        {
            result = 0;
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            {
                result = (uint)(c - '0');
                return true;
            }
            if (radix == 16uL)
            {
                c = (char)((int)c & -33);
                if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
                {
                    result = (uint)(c - 'A' + '\n');
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Oh right not come across that before - I'm glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Yep i dont think `BigInteger.Parse()` is available in silverlight.

You could use `Decimal` just without a decimal point, as a decimal value can go up to 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335.

(29 chars) if i counted correctly..

*Edit - the reason i chose `decimal` over `double` is that `decimal` has more significant figures and can therefore be more precise.